# Apply a function to each array in a list of arrays

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

Given a function f[x_,y_], and an array {{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...}, how would one go about applying the function to each {xn,yn}? I attempted using Map[f[#,#]&,array], but that applied the function like this  f[{x1,y1},{x2,y2}],f[{x3,y3},{x4,y4}].

Comment: Try `f @@@ array`

Comment: Right, look up the very first word of your title in the documentation: `Apply`.